# Gunicorn with flask app returning 502 error

Tags: gunicorn, flask

I've got an odd issue with a gunicorn server(serving a flask app) we run behind an amazon ELB.  The amazon ELB was throwing 502's intermittently when accessing different URLs on the gunicorn server.  There doesn't seem to be any one URL in particular that falls victim to these errors so I haven't been able to spot a pattern.  At first I assumed something was going wrong between gunicorn and the ELB causing the 502 error.  However I turned on access logs on gunicorn and noticed that gunicorn was in fact receiving and processing these requests, well, receiving them anyway:

```
100.111.0.0 - - [11/Feb/2019:13:42:37 +0000] "GET /page?args=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 502 "https://oursite.com/page" "<USER AGENT>"
```

It was responding with a 502 and that's the part that confuses me.  I was under the impression that 502 was something gateways returned (like an ELB or nginx operating in as a front end).  I'm not sure how 502 is even a valid return code for gunicorn as it isn't really a gateway to anything except the flask app behind it.  I checked the logs produced by the underlying flask app and nothing comes up at the timestamp from the logs above.  I also checked to see if the app developer actually was returning 502 anywhere and it doesn't look like they are.

I'd appreciate any help someone can offer on this topic.  Most posts I've found so far deal with the gateways in front of gunicorn being the ones returning 502 because they're having trouble talking to gunicorn itself.  But that doesn't seem to be the case here so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: This request did not return a 502 error. It returned a 200 OK, where the response body was 502 bytes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh good catch sir.  I can't believe I've been debugging this issue based on misreading that.  Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: You should check gunicorn's error log (stderr by default, so wherever you redirected that). 502 Bad Gateway from ELB means the backend either didn't answer the connection, (possibly because it wasn't fully started yet) or dropped the connection before sending a response. An uncaught Python exception would cause that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the tip( again:) ), we have been keeping an eye on stderr, and I have seen a couple of python exceptions.  However the number of exceptions doesn't line up with how many 502 errors we see, with later 502 errors not having any exceptions on the server side.  It seems there may be a communication issue between ELB and the back end(best guess).  I'm currently looking at keepalive values and the timeout values for the ELB to see if perhaps they should match up better.  We're still using default keepalive for gunicorn and 60sec for ELB.